# List of logging levels compatibility between Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-2.x, six

To have a list of logging levels in Python 2 I have to call this:

```
logging._levelNames.keys()
```

While Python 3 logging module has this:

```
list(logging._nameToLevel)
```

I am just adding `six` to my project to provide compatibility between Python 2 and Python 3. What is the cleanest way to figure out this compatibility issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn’t deliberately access a [attribute that starts with a `_`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1301346/6622817), it usually means that it’s a private attribute and that shouldn’t be used elsewhere.

And since the logging levels is just a short list, you can just copy and paste and create your own list instead:

```
levels = ['CRITICAL', 'FATAL', 'ERROR', 'WARN', 'WARNING', 'INFO', 'DEBUG', 'NOTSET']
```

Btw, if you noticed, the `logging._levelNames.keys()` and `list(logging._nameToLevel)` provides different results, the former also contains some integers `[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50]` while the latter does not.