# Python 3 level logging from uvicorn

Tags: python, logging

I have read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44733176/list-of-logging-levels-compatibility-between-python-2-and-python-3), along with many other resources, about logging in Python. I have created an `ini` file as follows to log the program's output. Although there are no errors during execution, there is an issue with the output. The content in `error.log` and `info.log` is correct, but I anticipated collecting all other lines of output in `log.log` file. However, it currently only captures `DEBUG` and `INFO` lines in `log.log`. I intend to include any line of output that is not labeled as `INFO` or `ERROR` in the `log.log` file, including lines printed by Python without any tag (stdout).

logging_config.ini:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,uvicorn

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,infoFileHandler,errorFileHandler,otherFileHandler

[formatters]
keys=consoleFormatter,infoFileFormatter,errorFileFormatter,otherFileFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,infoFileHandler,errorFileHandler,otherFileHandler

[logger_uvicorn]
level=INFO
handlers=consoleHandler,infoFileHandler,errorFileHandler,otherFileHandler
qualname=uvicorn
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=consoleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_infoFileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=infoFileFormatter
args=('info.log',)
filters=infoFilter

[handler_errorFileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=ERROR
formatter=errorFileFormatter
args=('error.log',)
filters=errorFilter

[handler_otherFileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=otherFileFormatter
args=('log.log',)
filters=otherFilter

[formatter_consoleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

[formatter_infoFileFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

[formatter_errorFileFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

[formatter_otherFileFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

[filter_infoFilter]
name=infoFilter
class=logging.Filter
level=INFO

[filter_errorFilter]
name=errorFilter
class=logging.Filter
level=ERROR

[filter_otherFilter]
name=otherFilter
class=logging.Filter
level=DEBUG
```

If you wonder how to use it, I use Uvicorn for the service, and here is the code for:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = {
        "host": "0.0.0.0",
        "port": 3000,
        "reload": True,
    }
    log_config_path = "logging_config.ini"

    uvicorn.run("app.api:app", **options, log_config=log_config_path)
```